# How to cut a string at an certain string in python?

Tags: pandas

I am working with python and want to cut a dataset before the following string occurs: "Customer Information". The goal is that everything before this string is inside my new dataset and the part after the string is cut out.

I have tried some things (2 ways) but it did not work. See Code attached below.

```
df = dataset.copy()
df.Description = df.Description.str.split('Customer Information').str[0].str.strip()

df['Description'] = [x.lstrip('').rstrip('Customer Information') for x in df['Description']]
```

The expected result for this string ("test Customer Information: Many lines of customer information") should be:

"test"

my actual result is: "test Customer Information: Many lines of customer information"

Comment: Given the test dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Description=["test Customer Information: Many lines of customer information"]))` This works for me: `df.Description.str.split('Customer Information').str[0].str.strip()`

Comment: Do not do `df.Description = ` Instead do `df['Description'] = `. Also `.rstrip` will not behave as you want in this case.

Comment: To avoid too many `str` accessors, you can do this `ci = "Customer Information"; df['Description'] = [s[:s.find(ci)].strip() for s in df.Description]`

Comment: Yes this works. Thank you. Given a Excel file as a dataset with many rows, how can this be done to every row, but not in every row of the excel appears  the string "Customer information".

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
df.Description=df.Description.str.split('Customer Information').str.get(0)
```

---

Here is how I tested:

```
   Item                   Description
0     1  abc Customer Information abc
1     1  aaa Customer Information abc
2     1  bbb Customer Information abc
3     1  ccc Customer Information abc
   Item Description
0     1        abc 
1     1        aaa 
2     1        bbb 
3     1        ccc
```

Comment: With this code i get the following error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rstrip'